# Dialog modals using decorators Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have various decorators preveting users to access different urls if they don't have filled data. I want to know what is the best way to show a modal with the data that user needs to be filled using decorators.

Comment: is the "filled data" data on their custom user class/User Profile?

Comment: Data that has to be filled is connected to django user via OneToOne relationship

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution myself: I' changed all the links to

```html
<a href="#" onClick="linkWrapper(<url_to>,'{{ request.path }}')">
```

Here is the linkWrapper function

```html
function linkWrapper(url_to,url_from)
{
    var content = '';
    $.ajax({ type: "GET", 
    url: url_to, 
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success : function(data){
        if (typeof data == 'object'){
            response = JSON.parse(data);
            if (response['error'] != undefined)
                if(typeof response['error'] == 'object')
                    ModalToggle(response['error']['url'],response['error']['url'],'#form',response['error']['title']);
                else
                    ToggleSimpleTextModal(response['error']['text'],'Ошибка доступа');
            else 
                window.location = url_from;
        }
        else
            window.location = url_to;
            
    }
    });
}
```

And all the decorator has to return is a json object which contains form url.